# How to debug what's wrong with this C++ class?

Tags: c++, class, int

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class emp
{
    public:
                int en;
                char name[10],des[10];
void get()
{
    cout<<"enter emp no.";
    cin>>en;
    cout<<"enter emp name";
    cin>>name;
    cout<<"enter designation";
    cin>>des;
}
};
class salary : public emp
{
public:
    float bp,hra,da,pf,np;
    void get1()
    {
    cout<<"enter basic pay";
    cin>>bp;
    cout<<"enter domestic allowance";
    cin>>da;
    cout<<"enter profit fund";
    cin>>pf;
    cout<<"enter human resource admittance";
    cin>>hra;
    }
    void calculate()
    {
        np=bp+da+hra-pf;
    }

    void display()
    {
        cout<<en<<"\t"<<name<<"\t"<<des<<"\t"<<da<<"\t"<<pf<<"\t"<<np<<"\n";

    }
    };

    int main()
    {
    salary s[10];
    int i,n;
    char ch;
    cout<<"enter the no. of employees";
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
     s[i].get();
     s[i].get1();
     s[i].calculate();
    }
    cout<<"\n eno. \t ename \t des \t bp \t hra \t da \t pf \t np \n";
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
     s[i].display();
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please describe the specific problem you facing

Comment: `cin>>name[10];` => `cin>>name;` Ditto with `des`

Comment: The names of the arrays are "name" and "des". I recommend a visit to [the book list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: I wrote it on CodeBlocks IDE and it shows "Red" mark on left margin which means error.( Tbh I am not an experienced programmer pls help)

Comment: What happens if I enter 15 letters for my name?

Comment: Answer:  Use `std::string`.

Comment: where to put the std::string @ThomasMatthews

Answer (score 2):

`cin>>des[10];` reads *one* (single) character for standard input, and attempts to write it to `des[10]`. Unfortunately, you've defined `des` as having 10 characters, so only `des[0]` through `des[9]` are valid, so when it attempts to write to `des[10]`, you get undefined behavior.

My guess is that you probably wanted something more like:

```
cin.getline(des, 10);
```

This attempts to read a maximum of 10 characters from `cin`, and write them to `des` (and assures that it's NUL terminated).

The same, of course, applies to `name`.

Once you're done with that, you probably want to forget all of the above, define both `name` and `des` as `std::string`s. Then you can use `std::getline(std::cin, name);`. With this you don't have to specify a maximum size; the string will expand to hold as much as the user enters.

Comment: shall i write the whole program so you understand better?

Answer (score 0):

instead of name[10] and des[10], use cin >> name and cin >> des